# How to write a linq query to search for a value in dataset and retrieve its row index

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, dataset

I have a Dataset ds in which i have two columns ITEM_ID and ITEM_VALUE. Now a linq query has to be written to search for a item id value and retrieve the row index of that value. i just don't have an idea need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `DataTable`, `DataSet` does not contain columns, it contains `DataTables`. So maybe this is what you want:

```
var rowIndex = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select((row,index)=>new{row,index})
                            .Where(x=>object.Equals(x.row["ITEM_ID"],yourItemID))
                            .Select(x=>x.index).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need. Plz try:

```
int index = ds.FindIndex(x => (x.ITEM_ID== given_ID) && (x.ITEM_VALUE== given_VALUE));
```

Comment: ds didn't give me any method called findindex

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as well

```
        DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
        int itemFind=993;
        int rowindex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dt.Select("ITEM_ID=" + itemFind).FirstOrDefault());
```